# URL syntax for searching post titles only (for RSS following)

Tags: search, urls, rss, feed

I am following a Wordpress site via the native RSS feeds for search result queries.

For example:

https://site.wordpress.com/search/ticket/feed/rss2/

But this seems to be searching all posts' content for the word "ticket". This results in too many unrelated posts in the feed. I only need updates for posts where the **title** contains the word "ticket". Is there a way I can modify the feed URL to achieve this?